# How to add custom attribute to shipping method in magento2

Tags: php, magento2, magento-2.0

I am trying to create a module in magento2 that would allow to add custom message to carrier or specific method. I successfully created admin section with grid and form. Now I am working on displaying this on frontend. I have created js and template file that works well if the data are in the estimate-shipping-methods result. I thought that the easiest way is to add this message to rate model. I've created a plugin

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement">
    <plugin name="hatimeria_shippingrateinfo_add_message_to_rates"
            type="Hatimeria\ShippingRateInfo\Plugin\ShippingMethodManagement"
            sortOrder="10"
            disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

Which fetches messages for current rates and adds them to model. Everything works well but this data is not then outputted to json result. As I found out magento does not simply ouput all data in the model but it returns only those that are defined by `ShippingMethodInterface`.
Then I noticed that there is something called extension_attributes and according to docs this should allow me to add my message to the result. So looking at [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html) and Magento_ProductVideo module I've done the following:

in `etc/extension_attributes.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodInterface">
    <attribute code="rate_info" type="Hatimeria\ShippingRateInfo\Api\Quote\Data\ShippingMethodInterface" />
</extension_attributes>
```

in `etc/di.xml`I added preference for my interface

```
<preference for="Hatimeria\ShippingRateInfo\Api\Quote\Data\ShippingMethodInterface" type="Hatimeria\ShippingRateInfo\Model\Rate\RateInfo" />
```

now classess, first interface in `Hatimeria\ShippingRateInfo\Api\Quote\Data\ShippingMethodIntarface.php`

```
namespace Hatimeria\ShippingRateInfo\Api\Quote\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensibleDataInterface;

/**
 * Shipping Rate Info data interface
 *
 * @api
 */
interface ShippingMethodInterface extends ExtensibleDataInterface
{

    const RATEINFO = 'rate_info';

    /**
     * Retrieve rate info message
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRateInfo();

    /**
     * Set rate info message
     *
     * @param string $rateInfo
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setRateInfo($rateInfo);
}
```

and class that actually implements this in `Hatimeria\ShippingRateInfo\Model\Rate\RateInfo.php`

```
namespace Hatimeria\ShippingRateInfo\Model\Rate;

use Hatimeria\ShippingRateInfo\Api\Quote\Data\ShippingMethodInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractExtensibleModel;

class RateInfo extends AbstractExtensibleModel implements ShippingMethodInterface
{
    /**
     * Retrieve rate info message
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRateInfo()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::RATEINFO);
    }

    /**
     * Set rate info message
     *
     * @param string $rateInfo
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setRateInfo($rateInfo)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::RATEINFO, $rateInfo);
    }
}
```

And this is not working. When rates are generated no additional extensions are returned by rate model. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you please help for http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159346/magento-2-add-custom-extesion-html-file-in-shipping-method-block this question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Below Steps:

1. Run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` to generate `ShippingMethodExtensionInterface` and a class that implements this (this is not done on each request even with disabled cache)
2. In your plugin instantiate `Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingMethodExtension` and add data to that object and then the entire object add to the entity with `$entity->setExtensionAttributes($extensionModel)`